# Generar un método que devuelva los estudiantes con las mejores calificaciones

Tags: javascript

Tengo que generar un método que devuelva los estudiantes con las mejores calificaciones. Gracias de antemano

`estudiantes` es un array de objetos `estudiante`. Crea un nuevo array con el nombre y apellido de los estudiantes.
que en sus propiedades "check1" y "check2", tengan una nota mayor o igual a "nota1" y "nota2" respectivamente.

```
    // Ej:
    /* var estudiantes = [
        { nombre: "Mengano", apellido: "Solis", check1: 16, check2: 8},
        { nombre: "Fulano", apellido: "Rodriguez", check1: 20, check2: 20},
        { nombre: "Zutano", apellido: "Alvarez", check1: 10, check2: 0},
        { nombre: "Perengano", apellido: "Leiria", check1: 17, check2: 19}
    ] */
     obtenerSoloLosMejores(estudiantes, 15, 15); 
     retorna => ["Fulanito Rodriguez", "Perengano Leiria"];


function obtenerSoloLosMejores(estudiantes, nota1, nota2) {
      var estudiantes = [
        { nombre: "Mengano", apellido: "Solis", check1: 16, check2: 8},
        { nombre: "Fulano", apellido: "Rodriguez", check1: 20, check2: 20},
        { nombre: "Zutano", apellido: "Alvarez", cintroducir el código aquíheck1: 10, check2: 0},
        { nombre: "Perengano", apellido: "Leiria", check1: 17, check2: 19}
        
        const check1 = array1.estudiantes(element => check1 > 15);
        const check2 = array1.estudiantes(element => check1 > 15);

console.log(check1);
console.log(check2);
    
};
```

Comment: Dejame ver si entiendo... ¿quieres devolver solo los estudiantes que tenga una nota mayor a un numero especifico?

Comment: Suena a que es una tarea que te mandaron en un curso. Tienes que replantear todo. Estas recibiendo parametros y por los nombres los estas redefiniendo dentro de la funcion. El objeto estudiantes debe ir fuera de la funcion y se lo debes pasar a la misma cuando la invocas. Lo mismo con las notas, que serian los 15 al parecer, debes usar lo que te viene como parametro. Luego las constantes check1 y 2 creo que pretendes generar un nuevo arreglo con los estudiantes con nota mayor a 15, debes usar la funcion map() para eso. Por ultimo tu funcion no devuelve nada, para eso deberias tener un return

Comment: @HernánGarcia en ese caso la función filter() sería mas apropiada, pero no entiendo bien Lo que quiere conseguir porque son dos notas diferentes

Comment: @J. VillasmiJ tienes razon, filter seria adecuado. Pero la verdad es que hay que replantear todo de nuevo. Me dieron ganas de hacerlo pero me suena a tarea de curso

Comment: hola J. Villasmil. si devo retornar el nombre de los estudiantes que tengan una nota superior a 15.

Comment: @ HernanGarcia @j.VillasmiJ. buenas como van? si devo retornar el nombre de los estudiantes que tengan una nota superior a 15.  gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

```js
var estudiantes = [
  { nombre: "Mengano", apellido: "Solis", check1: 16, check2: 8},
  { nombre: "Fulano", apellido: "Rodriguez", check1: 20, check2: 20},
  { nombre: "Zutano", apellido: "Alvarez", check1: 10, check2: 0},
  { nombre: "Perengano", apellido: "Leiria", check1: 17, check2: 19}
]

function obtenerSoloLosMejores(estudiantes, checkN, nota) {
      return estudiantes.filter(est => est[checkN] > nota)
};
// la funcion tiene tres parametros: el arreglo con los estudiantes, la propiedad por la cual vas a filtrar ( en esta caso puedes poner check1 o check2 al llamar a la función dependiendo de por cual quieras filtrar), y por ultimo el minimo de nota que debe tener
console.log(obtenerSoloLosMejores(estudiantes, 'check1', 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas hacer el check de las dos notas, probaría con algo así:

```
let estudiantes = [
        { nombre: "Mengano", apellido: "Solis", check1: 16, check2: 8},
        { nombre: "Fulano", apellido: "Rodriguez", check1: 20, check2: 20},
        { nombre: "Zutano", apellido: "Alvarez", check1: 10, check2: 0},
        { nombre: "Perengano", apellido: "Leiria", check1: 17, check2: 19}
]

function obtenerLosMejores(estudiantes, nota1, nota2){
        let mejores = estudiantes
        .filter(e => e.check1 > nota1 && e.check2 > nota2)
        .map(e => `${e.apellido} ${e.nombre}`);
        return mejores;
}

let mejoresEstudiantes = obtenerLosMejores(estudiantes, 15, 15);

console.log(mejoresEstudiantes);
```

En el filter recogemos los usuarios que tienen las notas necesarias y lo pasamos por un map, el cual devuelve un array con tantos elementos como el array que le pases. De este, solo devolvemos el apellido y nombre concatenados